# Whats the ~/.498731.padl file for?

Tags: macos

I just noticed a folder named `.498731.padl` in my home directory. What’s it for?

Here are its contents:

```
bplist00‘X$versionX$objectsY$archiverT$top�Ü†•U$null”   
WNS.keysZNS.objectsV$class°
Ä°ÄÄWPaddleT#A’j…˛M“Z$classnameX$classes\NSDictionary¢XNSObject_NSKeyedArchiver—TrootÄ#-27=CJR]dfhjlnvÑèò•®±√∆À����������������������������Õ
```

Comment: If you're correct then I'm guessing Visual Studio Code is the culprit.

Answer (score 15):

It looks like it's a binary property list file. You might be able to open it using `plutil -p .498731.padl` if you're curious about the contents.

Comment: This worked perfectly.

Comment: I have the exact same filename in my home directory. The contents displayed by plutil doesn't give much information on the origin of the file. It was last changed over a year ago. Any definitive information about its creator yet? Is Visual Studio the prime suspect?

Comment: I did find this info but I'm not on Windows and I've never used the indicated program. http://extension.nirsoft.net/padl

Answer (score 3):

It's related to the Xee license feature, not required by the Mac OS. 
You can check its text contents by:

```
plutil -p ~/.489614.padl
```

Comment: I can confirm that I have two `.NNNNNN.padl` files in my home directory and I once had the [Xee](https://theunarchiver.com/xee) picture viewer installed. The content of these binary plist files does not mention Xee at all. So I would have never guessed the origins of the file. Could I ask how you happen to know that Xee created them?